# Is there a way to test sliders using React Testing Library's `userEvent`?

Tags: react-testing-library

The React Testing Library docs specify that `userEvent` is to be preferred to `fireEvent`. However, I can't figure out a `userEvent` way to click to a particular value on a slider. With `fireEvent`, we can do:

```js
fireEvent.change(screen.getByRole('slider'), { target: { value: '3000' } })
```

Is this possible with `userEvent`? Or are there some capabilities that `fireEvent` has that `userEvent` does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is not currently possible - `userEvent` cannot test clicking a particular value on a slider, and using `fireEvent` is the correct approach. See [this issue](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/871) for details.